# Getting data to listview from xml childnotes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get all the tag type values to listview.
Don't really have a clear idea how to target them.

```
<Folder>
   <Ex>
      <Name>test1</Name>
      <Tags>
         <TagEx>
            <Name>Subject1</Name>
            <Tag Type="Maximum" Score="80" ExxTag="no">SUB1</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Average" Perc="31" ExxTag="no">SUB1</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Status" Results="2" ExxTag="no">SUB1</Tag>
         </TagEx>
      </Tags>
   </Ex>
   <Ex>
      <Name>test2</Name>
      <Tags>
         <TagEx>
            <Name>Subject2</Name>
            <Tag Type="Maximum" Score="100" ExxTag="no">SUB2</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Average" Perc="20" ExxTag="no">SUB2</Tag>
            <Tag Type="Status" Results="0" ExxTag="no">SUB2</Tag>
         </TagEx>
      </Tags>
   </Ex>
</Folder>
```

Tried collecting them to array with where x etc. but failed, only getting errors.
I'm very new with getting data from xml.

**Edit**: to clarify would like to get them in to a row or at least in arrays so I can set them in to a row(listview) like this: Ex Name, TagEx Name, Tag Type, Score, ExxTag, Tag Type, Perc, ExxTag, Tag Type, Results, ExxTag.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to get `TagEx->Name` too?

Comment: Yes I would like to get that too =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you will use this example to initialize a list of class object you will declare (TagEx class or something like that).
Here is an example with `System.Xml.Linq` of how to extract localnames, values, and attributes from this XML:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmldoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@"YOUR PATH");

    foreach (var name in xmldoc.Descendants("TagEx").Elements()
                        .Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Value = x.Value, Type=x.Attribute("Type")
                        , Score = x.Attribute("Score"),ExxTag=x.Attribute("ExxTag")}))
    {
        // Tag Name
        Console.WriteLine(name.Name.LocalName);
        // Tag Value
        Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
        // Type Attribute value
        Console.WriteLine(name.Type);
        // Score Attribute value
        Console.WriteLine(name.Score);
        // ExxTag Attribute value
        Console.WriteLine(name.ExxTag);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Name Subject1 Tag SUB1 Type="Maximum" Score="80" ExxTag="no" Tag SUB1
> Type="Average" ExxTag="no" Tag SUB1 Type="Status" ExxTag="no" Name
> Subject2 Tag SUB2 Type="Maximum" Score="100" ExxTag="no" Tag SUB2
> Type="Average" ExxTag="no" Tag SUB2 Type="Status" ExxTag="no"

Comment: problem with this thou is that if i use this to get all the values it gets lots of empty values in it. I need to get all 3 Tag type values from each in to a list. Like Perc and Results too. Made a sorter to get the empties out but this causes further problems when adding to list. Would like to get them in to a row like: Ex Name, TagEx Name, Tag Type, Score, ExxTag, Tag Type, Perc, ExxTag, Tag Type, Results, ExxTag.